# How to sort two vectors in one in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I need to write a function that receives two arrays (A[] and B[]) already sorted in ascending order, its function allocates a array C[] exactly with sum of the sizes of A and B, and interleaves the elements of A[] and B[] in C[], so that array C[] is ordered in ascending order. Write function as efficiently as possible. It is not to join the arrays and to order the array C[] using the Bubble method nor the Insertion.

Example:
A[] = { 1, 3, 6, 7} and B[] = {2, 4, 5}, the new vector is C[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

My code don't stop to run, what am I doing wrong?

```
def union(v1, v2):
    c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    auxv1 = 0
    auxv2 = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while i < len(v1)-1:
        auxv1 = v1[i]
    while j < len(v2)-1:
        auxv2 = v2[j]
    while k < len(c):
        if auxv1 < auxv2:
            c[k] = auxv1
            i += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            c[k] = auxv2
            j += 1
            k += 1
    if i == len(v1)-1 and j == len(v2)-1:
        return c
```

Comment: We can't use nested loops

Comment: What should happen for `while i < len(v1) - 1` to stop?

Comment: In Python you cannot do faster than `list(sorted(A + B))` since Python's sort is just amazingly fast (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). There are a number of problems with your code, to start with your first two while loops don't change the loop variable (i and j) and so will run forever...

Comment: Do you want us to debug ur code, or provide a novel solution?

Comment: @thebjorn merging two already sorted lists is `O(n)` in the worst case.

Comment: @bereal did you read the timsort link? It will likely do two run checks and a merge, and will be O(n) -- it will also be C-code (and correct ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn thanks, that's quite interesting. The OP is doing an exercise, though.

Comment: while i < len(v1)-1:
        auxv1 = v1[i]
    while j < len(v2)-1:
        auxv2 = v2[j]

you're not iterating i or j inside of those loops, so it never progresses i+=1, j+=1

that's why your code keeps running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just iterate over the two lists and append to the list `c` an element of `a` or of `b` according to which one is smaller.
An example is as follows.

```
c=[]
i = j = 0

while True:
    if j == len(b):
        c+=a[i:]
        break
    elif i == len(a):
        c+=b[j:]
        break
    elif a[i] < b[j]:
        c.append(a[i])
        i+=1
    else:
        c.append(b[j])
        j+=1
```

The time complexity of this approach is `linear` with respect to the length of the two lists.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. However, the program gives an error ("list index out of range - line 5") when I enter with 2 lists with the same length.

Answer (score 0):

@newbie has written a very clear algorithm that is also very fast -- the number of list operations it makes is exactly equal to the number of elements in the result, i.e. linear.

You can find a sub-linear algorithm though, by looking at runs of values from one list, that should be inserted before the next value from the other list.

I'm guessing this can perform faster on longer lists with large runs.. (as always when it comes to performance you'll need to test it, with your own data).

```
a = [1,3,6,7]
b = [2,4,5,9,11,12,13,14,15,16]
c = []

a1 = a2 = b1 = b2 = 0
alen = len(a)
blen = len(b)
clen = alen + blen

while a2 + b2 < clen:
    print "processed:", a2 + b2
    if b2 == blen:    # done with b..
        c += a[a1:]   # just append rest of a
        break         # and we're done
    else:
        # find indexes a1..a2 such that all items come before the next b
        next_b = b[b2]
        while a2 < alen and a[a2] < next_b:
            a2 += 1
        c += a[a1:a2]   # extend c with the chunk we've found
        a1 = a2

    if a2 == alen:    # we're done with a
        c += b[b1:]   # just append rest of b
        break         # and we're done
    else:
        next_a = a[a2]
        while b2 < blen and b[b2] < next_a:
            b2 += 1
        c += b[b1:b2]
        b1 = b2

print c
```